# Is it possible to observe data in domain usecase/interactor?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I want to know if it is possible to somehow observe the data in the domain layer's usecases classes, that are comming from repository. I would wanted to observe live data there, like in activity/fragement:

```
pictures.observe(...) { pictures -> }
```

Is it possible with LiveData or Flow?

Comment: What's the problem with observing in the viewmodel?

Comment: I want to receive from Room one object, and in bussines logic, so in domain I want to check if the object exists or not (null). That is why I don't want to check it in view model, but in usecase called CheckIfPictureExistsInDatabase and return boolean.

Comment: In dao I need to receive LiveData<List<Picture>> because when I'm trying to recive List<Picture> it gives me error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: This is what `flatMap`/`switchMap` is for

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is against the Clean Architecture principle. `LiveData`  is [lifecycle-aware](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), meaning it respects the lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or services. So it should be used in the UI layer.

[`LiveData.observe()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) method accepts `LifecycleOwner` as an argument, so you need somehow to pass the instance of `LifecycleOwner` to UseCase/Interactor.

There is also [`LiveData.observeForever()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observeForever(androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) method, which doesn't accept `LifecycleOwner` object, but [`LiveData.removeObserver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#removeObserver(androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) should be called to stop observing the `LiveData`.

Comment: what if you use kotlin `Flow` instead of live data? Does this also violate clean architecture principle?

Comment: To collect Flow a coroutine should be lauched using a CorotineScope. The latter should be bound to some lifecycle or be global(have a lifecycle of an app). If you want to transform data you can use different Flow's operators like map, flatMap etc.

Comment: I am only interested in transforming the `Flow` in UseCase i.e. the Flow is passed through the domain layer (and transformed) and then collected in viewModel with `viewModelScope`. Is there any violation here of clean architecture with this?

Comment: Not at all, there is no violation in transforming data.